# How to get the top name for each category from a Table? Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 Tables named Transactions,Customers and Tickets. Each ticket has a category (Theater,Cinema or Concert). I want to find the name of the person that made the most purchases foreach category:

For example:

```
Category | Name |  Purchases
 Theater   George      5
 Cinema     Tom        12
 Cinema     Mary       12
 Concert    John       7
```

```sql
WITH PurchasesSum AS (
    SELECT Category,Customers.Name,COUNT(Transactions.Customer_ID) AS Purchases,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(Transactions.Customer_ID) DESC) AS Rank
    FROM Transactions
    INNER JOIN Customers
        ON Transactions.Customer_ID= Customers.ID
    INNER JOIN Tickets
    ON Transactions.Ticket_num = Tickets.Ticket_num
    GROUP BY Name,Category
)

SELECT Name, Purchases,Category
FROM PurchasesSum 
ORDER BY Category ASC;
```

So far I got to this point, but it returns all of them
For example:

```
Category | Name |  Purchases
 Cinema     Tom        12
 Cinema     Mary       12
 Cinema     John       3
 Concert    John       7
 Concert    Tom        1
 Theater   George      5
 Theater   Mary        2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. Extend the  `OVER` clause of `rank()` to `PARTITION BY category` so that the rank is relative to the category. Then put a `WHERE` clause to the outer query filtering for a rank of one.

```
WITH
purchasessum
AS
(
SELECT category,
       customers.name,
       count(transactions.customer_id) purchases,
       rank() OVER (PARTITION BY category
                    ORDER BY count(transactions.customer_id) DESC) rank
       FROM transactions
            INNER JOIN customers
                       ON transactions.customer_id = customers.id
            INNER JOIN tickets
                       ON transactions.ticket_num = tickets.ticket_num
       GROUP BY name,
                category
)
SELECT name,
       purchases,
       category
       FROM purchasessum 
       WHERE rank = 1
       ORDER BY category ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postges, I recommend using `DISTINCT ON`.  Not only is it more concise, but it is often faster:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Category) Category, c.Name, 
       COUNT(*) AS Purchases,
FROM Transactions t JOIN
     Customers c
     ON t.Customer_ID = c.ID JOIN
     Tickets ti
     ON t.Ticket_num = ti.Ticket_num
GROUP BY Category, c.Name
ORDER BY Category, COUNT(*) DESC;
```